# Is it possible in ExpandableListView in Android to have different alignment for some children?

Tags: android, android-view

I've created an ExpandableListView and want few of my children to be aligned to the right instead of the left. I used the guide from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/). Is it possible to align only specific rows?

```
|Parent0            |
| child01           |
| child02           |
|           child03 |
| child04           |
|Parent1            |
|           child11 |
| child12           |
```

I guess you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

When creating the view in `getChildView()`, if the view is just a `TextView`, you could call `setGravity()` to left or right depending on which view type it is.

Or if the view is a layout, you could set the layout gravity for its children with `LayoutParams`.

Probably the easiest way is to have two child layouts in XML.  Then subclass `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, override `getChildTypeCount()` to return 2, override `getChildType()` to return 0 or 1 depending on which layout you want, and when overriding `getChildView()`, check the layout type using your `getChildType()` method and inflate one layout for 0 and the other layout for 1.